# Sumar valores en laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

Actualmente tengo un array que me devuelve estos valores [1, 1, 3] desde una query. Esta es la variable que uso  {{$media_gallery_groups}} donde me devuelve el array [1, 1, 3].
Me gustaría saber como puedo sumar los valores de array de la consulta 1+1+3 = 5

Tengo únicamente esto:

```html
@foreach ($media_gallery_groups as $gallery_medias)
   {{$gallery_medias}}                                    
@endforeach
```

Así logro obtener 1 1 3 pero quiero sumarlos para que me de el total.

Gracias y un saludo!

Comment: Tal vez usar [`array_reduce`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-reduce.php) sea la opción. Saludos

Comment: Quizás [ésto](https://parzibyte.me/blog/2019/07/17/sumar-valores-arreglo-php/) te pueda ayudar, me avisas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que veo estas haciendolo del lado del front, lo mas logico seria hacer esta suma en el modelo y llamarlo mediante un metodo o en el controlador segun lo que estes haciendo.
Para hacerlo desde el front podrias hacerlo de la siguiente manera (esoy asumiendo que usas blade por la sintaxis que compartis)

```
{{ array_sum($media_gallery_groups) }}
```